# What does it mean when a function is written like "name: function ()"?

Tags: javascript

I just have a super quick question about JavaScript so I'm not going to follow the general formatting of a question like usual.

I'm trying to understand some code in JavaScript, and the person who wrote it used a method that I'm not familiar with. As you see in the title, they've written it by typing the name of the function followed by a colon first, and then writing the actual function.

Example: `myFunction: function () {}`

Is anyone able to tell me what this means, why it's done, and what it accomplishes?

Comment: That is not a function. It is a method inside of an object.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/javascript/methods

Comment: Please do follow the usual question format, and post a [mcve], i.e. complete and runnable code

Comment: @Bergi If you look at my other questions, I'm normally very thorough with the correct formatting. However, this question is so quick that it doesn't really apply to the whole "My Problem, What I've Tried, My Code" concept. Also, there's not really a simple way to post a "minimal reproducible example" for a question that involves just a single line of code, which is why I only included it as a piece of inline code. I'll stick to the standard formatting from now on.

Comment: @leoprd The problem with the single line of code is that it means different things in different places. You'll need to provide some more context - the extract doesn't look like a  valid standalone script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is part of Object Methods like:

```
const person = {
  myFunction: function() {}
};
```

you can invoke `myfunction` by using `person.myFunction()`

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways of writing a function in JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {} // Function Declaration
myFunction: function () {} // Function Expression
myFunction = () => {} // Arrow Function
```